# Handle ashx handler POST results

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe, handler

I have an IFrame embedded in a web form, the IFrame has a submit button which calls an ashx handler, the handler does the server side work and return the response call by:

```
 context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
 context.Response.Write(someResultData);
```

How do I capture this response on the client side from outside or within the IFrame? Can I use javascript to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JavaScript to do that. If you use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) it's simple as:

```
$.post("your/file", function(data) {
       // data should contain your response
 });
```

You have to attach an event handler to the submit button click handler, or form submit event and do the above within that event handler method.

Comment: I can't do that, the submit button is within a PDF control, I can only modify the button to call the handler ashx which is under my control.